# How Shopify backend part in APP with VSCODE

Tags: visual-studio-code, shopify, vscode-debugger, shopify-app, shopify-api

I try to debug shopify backend part, for the frontend, there is no problem i follow

However for the backend part the endpoint remain "Unbound Breakpoint"

This link solutions work well for the frontend part, but not work for the backend!

```
https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-sdks/how-to-debug-shopify-react-app/td-p/601673
```

How resolte it ?

Comment: Can you pls provide us with some more info with which to answer you question? Yes you have provided keywords - but that's about it, so there really isn't enough for me to determine what issue you have with your backend debugging? I don't even know what your backend is? MERN? MEAN? The only thing we know is you're using React so you prob got node.  [Please please read this before and act upon it *they* get you and lock you away!  ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - seriously, even if you don't read the posting guide, the question form holds your hand and tells you what to ask.